# Is it possible to request an uncached file from a server?

Tags: http, caching, web, browser, server

My web-server is caching JavaScript files. As a result, it is impossible to debug most of my site. I am unable to turn off caching on the host's settings (business rule). I can confirm that the server caching is the problem because we flushed it and my browser was instantly able to get the newest version of the file. Additionally, FileZilla confirms that my uploads were successful.

Flushing the cache on the browser side has proven ineffective. I am able to edit .php files just fine.

Is it possible for a browser to request an un-cached version of a file?

Comment: Add a "cache buster" in the query string in the form of `?_=$timestamp`?

Comment: At the end of the js file url? Should $timestamp be something particular or just unique?

Comment: My boss just turned off server-caching so I'm afraid I'm unable to confirm if this works or not. But thank you for the help.